# Rails Average rounding down on it's own

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having an issue with averaging out some data in my rails 4 app and the output is rounding the number down on it's own accord. For example I want to average out a players goals.

```
[2,3]
```

Which should put output 2.5, but it's displaying 2.

Controller

```
@stats = Stat.where("playerId = ?", @player.playerId).group('year(gameDate)').select('AVG(goals) AS goals')
```

View

```
<% @stats.each do |s| %>
  <%= s.goals %>
<% end %>
```

I have tried

```
@goal = Stat.where("playerId = ?", @player.playerId).group('year(gameDate)').average(:goals)
```

But get the `BigDecimal` error. Removing the group part works, but I need to group by year.

Query

```
Player Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `players`.* FROM `players` WHERE `players`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `players`.* FROM `players` WHERE `players`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
  PlayerStat Load (0.3ms)  SELECT gameDate, AVG(goals) AS goals GROUP BY year(gameDate)  ORDER BY year(gameDate) DESC
Rendered players/_season.html.erb (1.1ms)
```

Comment: Can you please share the query that is being generated? Should show up in console.

Comment: sure. added above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of average will be typecast to the column's datatype. If your goals column is an integer value, average method will return an integer value only.

[Reference](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/average)